# Angular Typescript create class for array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm still a beginner with programming, and struggle with the informatie that is available about TypeScript. I want to create object:

```
import { info } from '../info';
Information: info {
name: 'John',
id: 5,
comments: [
    {
    rating: 5,
    comment: 'some text'
    },
    {
    rating: 20,
    comment: 'another text'
    },
    {
    rating: 4,
    comment: 'hello world!'
    }
]};
```

How I should initialize a class?

```
export class info {
name: string,
id: number,
comments: ???    }
```

Comment: use `any` type.

Comment: but it's not dinamic content.I know all variables. And if I use any, i can't set type of rating and comment

Comment: You can complete the definition of your class, add a constructor to initiate the class variables, and then instantiate the class using `const instance = new ClassName(...);`

Comment: Never use `any` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a file called `info.ts` in the same directory as your business logic.  `info.ts` looks like this:

```
export class Comment {
  rating: number;
  comment: string;

  constructor(rating: number, comment: string) {
    this.rating = rating;
    this.comment = comment;
  }
}

export class Info {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  comments: Comment[];

  constructor(id: number, name: string, comments: Comment[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.comments = comments;
  }
}
```

Then in the file you want to use the classes:

```
import { Info, Comment } from './info';

...
...

const comments = [new Comment(2, 'his comment'), new Comment(4, 'her comment')];
const info = new Info(99, 'John', comments);
```

... do something with info... or whatever

** Side Note **

If the class definition file `info.ts` is not in the same dir as your business logic, you just have to use a relative path.

Sometimes, you can get in nasty situations with relative paths when you have crap like this `../../../../../info.ts` and then have to move the file... sometimes the IDEs don't accurately update all of the relative paths.  Check out this article for a better way of handling that by configuring tsconfig to allow you to define module resolutions:

https://netbasal.com/sexier-imports-in-typescript-e3c645bdd3c6

That article focuses on Angular, but the same thing can be done with node.js... it's just way trickier given how node builds and resolves modules.

Comment: no problem, i didn't test this.. just wrote the code in the SO editor.. so if something's wrong, just say so in a comment.

Comment: also, accept the answer if this solved your problem.